# Vector field doesn't vanish in a simply connected region

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Suppose I have the following vector field $$\underline{G} = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\underline{i}+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\underline{j}$$ this is clearly defined for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, i.e. the $z$ axis.

Suppose I want to find the work along the unit circle $C$ centred at the origin and lying on the plane $z=0$, parametrised as $\underline{r}(t) = \cos(t)\underline{i}+\sin(t)\underline{j}$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. Now if we calculate the line integral we see that $$\int_C\underline{G}\cdot d\underline{r} = 2\pi\neq 0$$

the reason I gave in the question was that this happens because the region inside the circle is not simply connected, indeed we cannot shrunk the circle to the origin!

Then I tried to show this even further and say, consider the unit circle centered at $(2,2)$ (so it doesn't contain the origin, nor the axes) then the work along $C_2 : \underline{r}_2(t) = (\cos(t)+2)\underline{i}+(\sin(t)+2)\underline{j}$ should be zero as the region there is simply connected! However it is not zero..

where did I go wrong? Are my assumptions wrong?

**Edit**

It works indeed, wrote it wrong on Mathematica[image: Integral]

Comment: You have here a two dimensional vector field: what $\;z\,-$ axis are you thinking about??

Comment: Of course the unit disk (*any* disk!) is simply connected...and even shrinkable to the origin or to any other point in the disk. Perhaps you meant the disk **without the origin** ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio, sorry i miswrote the question, it should be on the $z=0$ plane

Comment: Then you're missing a whole coordinate all along...I think you actually mean two dimensional business here.

Comment: Can you show your calculation where you got something different from 0?

Comment: @Cat That is pretty simple with the given standard parametrization of the unit circle.

Comment: @DonAntonio , basically the circle is on the $z=0$ axis, and of course the $\underline{k}$ component of the vector field is $0$

Comment: @Euler_Salter All this is a minor thing as nothing really important changes, but why do you insist on three dimensions?

Comment: @donantonio yes I know how to calculate it myself. I am asking the OP to show their work so we can help

Comment: @DonAntonio, how am I missing a coordinate? The vector field has $0$ constant value in the $z$ direction so that all the calculations happen on the plane!

Comment: @Cat I didn't really solve it, I just used Mathematica and it gave a value close to zero, but not zero, something like $\pi-\sqrt{2}\pi$

Comment: Perhaps you entered something incorrectly into mathematica then. Green's Theorem ensures that it will be 0

Comment: @Cat I'll try again now, I will update. So in general it works for any simple closed path not containing the origin right?

Comment: Yes, again, by Green's Theorem.

Comment: @Cat what I thought indeed, I just wasn't sure that the rest of the plane was actually simply connected. Indeed I was told that the "simply-connectedness" is not really equivalent to "no-holes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the integral on the unit circle around $\;(2,2)\;$ is zero, and the reason is simple: the vector field has a potencial function there:

$$\phi(x,y)=\arctan\frac yx$$

so the value of the integral around the unit circle centered at $\;(2,2)\;$ is zero...and in fact, over any closed, simple smooth curve not containing  the origin.

Comment: hold on, how did you see the $arctan$ function? That's pure wizardry

Comment: @Euler_Salter That's a simple indefinite integral: if there's a function $\;\phi\;$ such that $\;G=\nabla\phi\;$ , then it **must be** that $\;\phi_x'=-\frac y{x^2+y^2}\;$ , so just integrate this wrt $\;x\;$ and you get  $\;\arctan\frac yx+K(y)\;$ , the last summand a constant wrt $\;x\;$ , and then do $\;\phi_y'\;$ and compare to the second coordinate of $\;G\;$ and you're done. Basic stuff in vectorial analysis.

Comment: I was more concerned about the actual derivative of the arctan function but I guess that's because of my bad memory then

Comment: @DonAntonio: might as well be honest. Did you really do the integration here? Euler_Salter, the truth is that your vector field is a standard counterexample: this may be over your head, but your field $F$, interpreted as a differential form, is the pullback of the volume form $d\theta$ of the unit circle $S^1$, and $\theta$ for the unit circle is defined by $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$. Most mathematicians will recognize this instantly without having to do the integration, because most have seen this example before.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Might as well be cautious: I've been teaching stuff like this for tens of years so I know it pretty well. Nevertheless, the integration here is pretty basic, almost immediate, and what I wrote in my above comment to Euler is meant to teach him the general way to do these things...Your "pullback", "differential form", etc. description can sound like martian to somebody asking as basic a question as this one> most probably hasn't yet even seen the beginning of differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The integral should come  to zero. We have 
$$G(r_2(t)) = \frac{-\sin t-2}{4\cos t+4\sin t+9}\mathbf{i}+\frac{\cos t+2}{4\cos t+4\sin t+9}\mathbf{j}$$
$$r_2'(t) = -\sin(t)\mathbf{i}+\cos(t) \mathbf{j}$$
And so
$$G(r_2(t))\cdot r_2'(t) = \frac{1+2\sin t +2\cos t}{4\cos t+4\sin t +9} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{3.5}{4\cos t+4\sin t+9}$$
The integral of which should come out to zero.

Alternatively, define $f$ in the upper half plane, so that for $x\geq 0$ we have $f(x,y) = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$, and for $x < 0$, $f(x,y)=\pi+\tan^{-1}{y/x}$. That is, given $(x,y)$ in the upper half plane, $f$ gives us the polar angle (between $0$ and $\pi$). Then $G = \nabla f$, and so all integrals around a closed curve should be zero.

Note: The reason this doesn't work on $\Bbb{R}^2$ is because the polar angle cannot be defined in a continuous manner on the whole plane.

Comment: shouldn't it be an $8$ instead of a $9$?

Comment: When you expand the denominator, you get a $\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t$, which adds $1$ to the constant term.

Comment: fair point, didn't see that